# Query PostGIS raster table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgis-raster

I would like to know if it is possible to query a PostGIS raster directly in QGIS in the same way one can use the query builder to filter a vector layer? I have successfully built database views of PostGIS rasters as explained in the following post [How to view a postgis raster query in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144665/how-to-view-a-postgis-raster-query-in-qgis).

I was wondering if there is any way to access and query the attributes of the raster table directly in QGIS - I am using the latest version of QGIS 3.

I currently have an atlas that dynamically filters several vector layers based on the atlas features (@atlas_feature). I would like to be able to do the same with my PostGIS raster - thus avoiding the overhead of creating several views and manually (or through code) turning them on and off based on the atlas pages.